# copy directory to another from add_custom_target

Tags: cmake

I have this target code:

```
add_custom_target (
        dist
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/po ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMMAND ${7Z} a -t7z ${PACKER_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME_EXT} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        COMMENT "${PACKER_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME_EXT} created"
    )
```

My goal is to copy directory (and its contents) to my directory `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}`. The only file in the directory is CMakeLists.txt, the rest are just bunch of empty "src", "data" and "po" files, any ideas

Comment: What is the question? Does your code work?

Answer (score 0):

You do it wrong. There is a better way to produce a distribution tarball.
Use [`install`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/install.html) command and [`CPack`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CPack.html) module.
[Here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack) you may find a brief tutorial on `CPack` with example project.

Comment: Indeed I know about CPack, I'm not trying to create a distribution, I'm trying to compress some files of my proyect...

Comment: then use `install` that _some_ files into a separate `COMPONENT` and use `CPack` to make an archive of any type you want (with that set of files).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a directory you should use `cmake -E copy_directory`.

But if you want to create a source package, please have a look into cpack, it can also create source packages.